# How to compare 2 array with same key but different value PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I want to ask about compare 2 arrays with same key but different value.

I have 1 array master (`arrayMaster`) and 2 or more array data (`arrayData1`, `arrayData2`, and maybe could be more). These array data key will have exactly one of `arrayMaster` data key (I've done for this thing). For data example that I get:

```
arrayMaster = Array( [apple] => 1 [banana] => 2 [choco] => 1 [donut] => 2 [egg] => 1 )
arrayData1 = Array( [apple] => 8 [banana] => 2 [choco] => 1 )
arrayData2 = Array( [donut] => 5 [choco] => 2 [egg] => 3 )
```

(We can see that `arrayData1` and `arrayData2` contain a key from `arrayMaster` key.)

These arrays I want to compare and give a calculating method. If the array key at `arrayData(n)` found at `arrayMaster`, it will do a calculating data, let said it will sum each other.

So, the result is:

```
arrayResult1 = 1+8 (apple have 1 from master, apple have 8 from arrayData1), 2+2, 1+1
arrayResult2 = 2+5 (donut have 2 from master, donut have 5 from arrayData2), 1+2, 1+3
```

So I will have 2 new array (or more, depend on how much arrayData) that contain:

```
arrayResult1 = ([apple] => 9 [banana] => 4 [choco] => 2);
arrayResult2 = ([donut] => 7 [choco] => 3, [egg] => 4);
```

Anyone know how to do this? I’”ve tried `array_intersect` but it didn’t work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write something simpler like this..

```
function modifyArr(&$arr,$basearray) //<=-- See I am passing & (reference) so your original array will be modified
{
foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
 {
    if(array_search($k,$basearray)!==null)
    {
        $arr[$k]=$basearray[$k]+$arr[$k];
    }
 }
}

modifyArr($arrayData1,$arrayMaster); //<=-- Pass your 1st array
modifyArr($arrayData2,$arrayMaster); //<=-- Pass your 2nd array
```

<kbd>[Demonstration](https://eval.in/149502)</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

Do something like this:

```
function doCalc($master, $slave) {
    $results = array();

    foreach( $slave as $key => $value ) {
        if( !isset($master[$key]) ) {
            $results[$key] = $value;
        }
        else {
            $results[$key] = $master[$key] + $value;
        }
    }

    return $results;
}

$arrayResult1 = doCalc($arrayMaster, $arrayData1);
$arrayResult2 = doCalc($arrayMaster, $arrayData2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using these as examples:

```
arrayResult1 = 1+8 (apple have 1 from master, apple have 8 from arrayData1), 2+2, 1+1
arrayResult2 = 2+5 (donut have 2 from master, donut have 5 from arrayData2), 1+2, 1+3
```

Why not just do this:

```
// The main arrays for master & data values.
$arrayMaster = array('apple' => 1, 'banana' => 2, 'choco' => 1, 'donut' => 2, 'egg' => 1);
$arrayData1 = array('apple' => 8, 'banana' => 2, 'choco' => 1);
$arrayData2 = array('donut' => 5, 'choco' => 2, 'egg' => 3);

// Set a values to check array.
$values_to_check = array('apple', 'donut');

// Init the results array.
$results_array = array();

// Roll through the values to check.
foreach ($values_to_check as $value) {

  // Check if the array key exists in '$arrayMaster'.
  if (array_key_exists($value, $arrayMaster)) {

    // If it exists, add it to the '$results_array'.
    $results_array[$value][] = $arrayMaster[$value];

    // Check if the array key exists in '$arrayData1'.
    if (array_key_exists($value, $arrayData1)) {
      // If it exists, add it to the '$results_array'.
      $results_array[$value][] = $arrayData1[$value];
    }

    // Check if the array key exists in '$arrayData2'.
    if (array_key_exists($value, $arrayData2)) {
      // If it exists, add it to the '$results_array'.
      $results_array[$value][] = $arrayData2[$value];
    }

  }

}

// Roll through the results array and use 'array_sum' to get a sum of values.
foreach ($results_array as $results_key => $results_value) {
  echo $results_key . ' : ' . array_sum($results_value) . '<br />';
}
```

But looking at your example, I am unclear on why you have separate arrays for `$arrayData1` and `$arrayData2` so here is the same code, but refactored to have nested arrays in `$arrayData` which should be more efficient:

```
// The main arrays for master & data values.
$arrayMaster = array('apple' => 1, 'banana' => 2, 'choco' => 1, 'donut' => 2, 'egg' => 1);
$arrayData = array();
$arrayData[] = array('apple' => 8, 'banana' => 2, 'choco' => 1);
$arrayData[] = array('donut' => 5, 'choco' => 2, 'egg' => 3);

// Set a values to check array.
$values_to_check = array('apple', 'donut');

// Init the results array.
$results_array = array();

// Roll through the values to check.
foreach ($values_to_check as $value) {

  // Check if the array key exists in '$arrayMaster'.
  if (array_key_exists($value, $arrayMaster)) {

    // If it exists, add it to the '$results_array'.
    $results_array[$value][] = $arrayMaster[$value];

    // Roll through the values to check.
    foreach ($arrayData as $arrayData_value) {
      // Check if the array key exists in '$arrayData1'.
      if (array_key_exists($value, $arrayData_value)) {
        // If it exists, add it to the '$results_array'.
        $results_array[$value][] = $arrayData_value[$value];
      }
    }

  }

}

// Roll through the results array and use 'array_sum' to get a sum of values.
foreach ($results_array as $results_key => $results_value) {
  echo $results_key . ' : ' . array_sum($results_value) . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: what is that `area_key_exists` ? please correct it.. it should be `array_key_exists`.

Comment: Hi JakeGould, if I use Your code, theres only check apple and banana, what I want is check all key in array.. But nevermind, use Shankar method and it works perfectly... Thanks for Your help too..