# How to check is php array have different value of key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [job_id] => 100
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [job_id] => 100
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [job_id] => 101
        )
)
```

Now here how to check if "job_id" is different. eg all have same job_id or not and how many different job_id array have.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare 2 array with same key but different value PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589377/how-to-compare-2-array-with-same-key-but-different-value-php)

Comment: @Daniyal I want it with same array not want to compare with other array. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using array function:

```
$data = Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [job_id] => 100
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [job_id] => 100
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [job_id] => 101
    )
)
$totalDifferentJobId = count(array_unique(array_column($data, 'job_id')));
```

It will give you total unique job

Comment: @Nawin $data is your array. Don't copy my $data variable. just assign your array to $data variable. It will works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if it is not a too large array, you can do the following:

```
<?php

$arr = [
    ['id' => 1, 'job_id' => 100],
    ['id' => 2, 'job_id' => 100],
    ['id' => 3, 'job_id' => 101]
];

$jobids = array_unique(array_column($arr, 'job_id'));

var_dump($jobids);
```

This looks like a db-result, in wich case it would be better to use a group-by statement?